# Python 2 print invalid syntax: Raspberry Pi

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi

I was trying to make a program, just to test that it works i made a simple "Hello world" program. It is coded like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-

print 'hello world'
```

Then I get the error code:

```
File "New.py", line 4
   print ?hello world?
         ^
Syntax Error: invalid syntax
```

It doesn't even show the ' why is this? I have also tried using parentheses in case I had python 3 but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried using double quotes instead of single quotes, what happens then? I ran your code and it worked on my machine, but it looks like there is some problem with your quotes being interpreted as question marks

Comment: What does `python --version` give you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try taking away the space and using double quotes

Comment: Thank you for the help. It worked immediately once I used double quotes.